# Method for showing list elements

Tags: c#

I have list in class

```
public List<Igrac> Igraci { get; set; } = new List<Igrac>();
```

The class:

```
class Igrac
{
    public string Ime { get; set; }
    public string Prezime { get; set; }
    public string Pozicija { get; set; }
    public int Godine { get; set; }
    public Igrac(string Ime, string Prezime, string Pozicija, int Godine)
    {
        this.Ime = Ime;
        this.Prezime = Prezime;
        this.Pozicija = Pozicija;
        this.Godine = Godine;
    }
}
```

Added new list elements:

```
noviklb.DodavanjeIgraca(new Igrac("Petar", "Petrovic", "Krilo", 1992));
noviklb.DodavanjeIgraca(new Igrac("Badr", "Hari", "Napad", 1993));
```

The method for adding is working OK. The problem is that when I use `Console.WriteLine` I get an error like this:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[zadatak.Program+Igrac]

I Googled and foreach is solution but I cant do it right. Do I need to write foreach as method?

Comment: `string.Join` and override `.ToString()`

Comment: Where should i put that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Igrac
    {
        public string Ime { get;  }
        public string Prezime { get;  }
        public string Pozicija { get;  }
        public int Godine { get; }
        public Igrac(string Ime, string Prezime, string Pozicija, int Godine)
        {
            this.Ime = Ime;
            this.Prezime = Prezime;
            this.Pozicija = Pozicija;
            this.Godine = Godine;
        }
    }

public override string ToString()
{
   return $"{Ime} {Prezime} {Pozicija} {Godine}";
}
```

Now you can use.

```
string myStringDate = new Igrac("Petar", "Petrovic", "Krilo", 1992).ToString();
```

ALSO NOTE: It would be good to make you properties get only.
Working link:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/zMNiln

Comment: Tnx now working. Any chance for writing method for counting list ? and biggest intiger in list? 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/a3hqVN

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
public void showList(List<Igrac> noviklb)
{
  foreach (var item in noviklb)
  {
        Console.WriteLine("Ime : " + item.Ime);
        Console.WriteLine("Prezime : " + item.Prezime);
        Console.WriteLine("Pozicija : " + item.Pozicija);
        Console.WriteLine("Godine  : " + item.Godine);
        Console.WriteLine("Get New Record****************** ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Working,so now i need to write method for counting list elements,
public int prebrojavanje()
            {
                return Igraci.Count();
            }
soo,this does not working